# Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount not recognized as cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-analysis-services

Getting error while running Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount with proper parameters

**Script:** Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -Credential $Credential -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -RolloutEnvironment  $rolloutEnvironment

**ERROR:** Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount: The term 'Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.

I checked and could see that required module (**AzureRM.AnalysisServices**) is already installed and is imported in the script

Comment: try upgrading it? or, perhaps, you are using the new az module? then try add-azanalysisservicesaccount?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks for your reply. But no luck!

Comment: Could it solve your issue?

Comment: It did not worked either! But I resolved the issue by using REST API call!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to make sure you have installed the [`Azure.AnalysisServices`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.AnalysisServices/0.5.4) module, the `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount` belongs to it not the `AzureRM.AnalysisServices` module.

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.analysisservices/add-azureanalysisservicesaccount?view=azurermps-5.7.0), it looks the command belongs to `AzureRM.AnalysisServices`.

[image]

But actually we could not find it in the **Package Details** in [`AzureRM.AnalysisServices`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.AnalysisServices/0.6.14), and we can find it in [`Azure.AnalysisServices`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.AnalysisServices/0.5.4).